# maven assembly plugin: control over directories

Tags: maven

I'm trying to convert some groovy (gradle) code to maven. Where possible, we're trying to use off-the-shelf plugins rather than custom ones.

We wanted to use the maven assembly plugin to assemble a tar file that we'll use for deployment.  The directory structure is important for our deployment tools, and I seem to be fighting against getting maven to get it to do what I want.

The key problem on the bottom code snippet is the fact that the jar ended up in a `target` directory in the tar file. My question is: can this be avoided? or should I cut my losses and write a simple custom plugin to do this?

(its possible I'm putting 2 and 2 together and getting 5, but it does seem related to this bug [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-45))

Directory structure (After running the build)

```
.
└── project1
    ├── config
    │   └── foo.config
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   └── main
    │       ├── assembly
    │       │   └── assembly.xml
    │       └── java
    │           └── com
    │               └── foo
    │                   └── bar
    │                       └── App.java
    └── target
        ├── archive-tmp
        ├── classes
        │   └── App.class
        ├── maven-archiver
        │   └── pom.properties
        ├── my-static-jar-name-bundle.tar
        └── my-static-jar-name.jar
```

Assembly file

```
<assembly>
    <id>bundle</id> 
    <formats>
        <format>tar</format>
    </formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/spooge</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>appconfig</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
                <include>**/*.config</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

contents of the tar file when the build has finished (note the jar is in a 'target' subfolder)

```
tar xvf project1/target/my-static-jar-name-bundle.tar 
x spooge/target/my-static-jar-name.jar
x appconfig/foo.config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the fileset as shown:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/spooge</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.jar</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

The way it's currently configured, the assembly plugin is searching `project1`s entire directory for any jar files.  The only one it finds is in the `target` directory, so Maven happily includes it in the tar.  The change I suggest uses `project1/target` as the starting point, so I think you'll get the result you want.